# ESLint: 'handleVar' is missing in props validation(react/prop-types)

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am working on a project using React and eslint but I got the following error :

```
ESLint: 'handleVar' is missing in props validation(react/prop-types)
```

Here is my code :

```
const Test = (props) => {
 
  return (
        <div className="form-inline row" style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>
          <Select placeholder="Test" id="6" handleVar={props.handleVar} />
        </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Do you know how can I solve that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: You got that error because your  React props aren't typed, do you use a type library such as PropTypes, TypeScript or Flow ?
The React doc: https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: I defined `handleVar` like that :   `handleVar={(showVar) => {
          setOnlyvar(showVar[0]);
        }}`

Comment: Do you use a type library such as PropTypes, TypeScript or Flow ?

Comment: no only jsx actually

Comment: So you have 2 options:
- Disable the eslint rule (not recommended)
- Follow React recommendations: https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Yes but I don't use class only function actually :/

Comment: It works you both class and function components

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you don't use a Type Checking Library like PropTypes, TypeScript or Flow.

More info about the error:

- [Prevent missing props validation in a React component definition (react/prop-types)](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md)
- [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

[React recommend to use TypeScript or Flow instead of PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html) but here is a working example with PropTypes:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Test = (props) => {
 
  return (
        <div className="form-inline row" style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>
          <Select placeholder="Test" id="6" handleVar={props.handleVar} />
        </div>
  );
};

Test.propTypes = {
  handleVar: PropTypes.func
};

export default Test;
```